# how to pass data from child window to parent window using lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

how can i pass the data from child window to parent window using lightning web component

- to populate the new window i used this code
  popup = window.open("fileName", "Popup", "width=600,height=700");
      popup.focus();

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/lightning-message-service-developer-preview.html) to communicate between windows.

Source Example:

```
// myPublisherComponent.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { createMessageContext, releaseMessageContext,
         publish } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SAMPLEMC from "@salesforce/messageChannel/SampleMessageChannel__c";
 
export default class MyPublisherComponent extends LightningElement {
    context = createMessageContext();
     
    publishMC() {
        const message = {
            recordId: "some string",
            recordData: { value: "some value" }
        };
        publish(this.context, SAMPLEMC, message);
    }
     
    disconnectedCallback() {
        releaseMessageContext(this.context);
    }
}
```

Destination Example:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { createMessageContext, releaseMessageContext
         subscribe, unsubscribe } from 'lightning/messageService';
 
import SAMPLEMC from "@salesforce/messageChannel/SampleMessageChannel__c";
 
export default class MySubscriberComponent extends LightningElement {
    context = createMessageContext();
    subscription = null;
    @track receivedMessage = '';
   
    subscribeMC() {
       if (this.subscription) {
           return;
       }
       this.subscription = subscribe(this.context, SAMPLEMC, (message) => {
           this.handleMessage(message);
       });
    }
   
    unsubscribeMC() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription);
        this.subscription = null;
    }
 
    handleMessage(message) {
        this.receivedMessage = message ? JSON.stringify(message, null, '\t') : 'no message payload';
    }
 
    disconnectedCallback() {
        releaseMessageContext(this.context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom events and dispatch them from the child component to parent component. Refer to this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch

Comment: Events don't work across windows, except for a few special cases, such as the `message` event, and even then, you wouldn't construct an eent for that.